# Find the source that added the following html in a page on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

After visiting a web page I created and visit often on Firefox, a modal covering the window appeared for the first time and a mysterious DOM node was created at the end of the document body.

The following code was injected:

```html
<div>
  <style>
    .overlay {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;height: 100%;width: 100%;position: fixed;z-index: 9999999;top: 0;left: 0;  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.85);overflow-x: hidden;transition: 0.5s;}.overlay-content {position: relative;top: 25%;width: 100%;text-align: center;margin-top: 30px;}.overlay a {padding: 8px;text-decoration: none;font-size: 36px;color: #818181;display: block;transition: 0.3s;}.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {color: #f1f1f1;}.overlay .closebtn {position: absolute;top: 20px;right: 45px;font-size: 60px;}@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {  .overlay a {font-size: 20px}  .overlay .closebtn {font-size: 40px;top: 15px;right: 35px;  }}
  </style>
  <div id="showHomebrewOverlayOuter" class="overlay">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" id="showHomebrewOverlay1" rel="nofollow">×</a>
    <div class="overlay-content">
      <a href="#" id="showHomebrewOverlay2" rel="nofollow">Continue</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The page is hosted on gh-pages, there are no commits adding such a component and there were no additional network requests for unfamiliar files.

Both links have the same event handler running a function located in a .xpi add-on file in the Firefox Extensions folder.

I unzipped the .xpi and inspected the extension's code, which seems pretty normal for what it is intended to do, but nowhere can I find the code creating the aforementioned node nor the IDs and class names.

I have been using the extension for a while now without encountering the same issue. The add-on itself hasn't been updated the past few months either so it's really peculiar.

I assume that this can't be a gh-pages issue since the handler calls a function located in a local file.
Is Firefox able to take this action to lead the user into re-running the addon's code post installation?
Have you encountered such behavior before?

The extension in question is https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/translater-for-all-languages/ .

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the reason as they may be adding the new modal window which are dynamically adding in your window document. And thus it adds at the end of the document.

This may be looks very suspicious to you when you inspects your DOM elements.

Yes, this kind of coding and techniques are very generic. I often use third party add-ons as such as KendoUI or Infrastructure UI. It has similar techniques which is acceptable.